# ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-YYFUnW/psycopg2/

Tags: django

I'm trying to  install requirements.txt file in python 2.7 in ubuntu but i get ERROR:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-YYFUnW/psycopg2/

What exactly does that mean, and how do I fix it? I already tried these commands:

```
apt-get install python-bs4
sudo install --upgrade setuptools
sudo apt-get update
```

Error Image :

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error can occur because of the version of `psycopg2==2.6.2` you are trying to install. I did face this error while installing this version of `psycopg2`. So to avoid this error, you can use another version of it or the latest version as:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Also, **psycopg2** is going to be renamed from release of version 2.8, so it is recommended to install it using:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

If you are installing **psycopg2** from a `requirements.txt` file, you can comment out the package listed in the file as:

```
# psycopg2==2.6.2
```

Then install the package as suggested above, then install other requirements from the file with the package name still commented.

Comment: It would be nice if you could create a new post for additional queries as it is not preferred to ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: You can provide the django tag if it is related to django, then I can easily find it.

Comment: You can post the link for your question here in comment too.

Comment: Ok .I'm trying to solve the issue. If I can't solve the issue I will post the link here @Sanip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56834263/unable-to-deploy-django-project-on-apache-with-virtualenv-and-mod-wsgi @Sanip