# Unable to deploy django project on apache with virtualenv and mod_wsgi

Tags: django

I'm trying to run django project with mod_wsgi and apache.I have installed virtual environment and I included `bps.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. I  could not run the project on browser. When I run python manage.py runserver ,it gives me "Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? " error.

[settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEiPE.jpg) [Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsV8o.jpg) [bps.conf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfHtk.jpg) [Tables list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvcJf.jpg) [Users list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGJgN.jpg) [Server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZk2R.jpg)

Comment: What is the response when you are accessing application from browser, have you restarted Apache after configuration?

Comment: This error may be a database connection error, if you are using postgresql.

Comment: Yes ,I restarted Apache. When I run localhost on browser , it displays Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page @kamran

Comment: yes i'm using postgresql@Sanip

Comment: Try starting the postgresql service by `sudo service postgresql start`

Comment: Do i have to make separate .wsgi file if i included mod_wsgi.so file in bps.conf?

Comment: I don't have any idea on the side of apache server. Sorry for that but the error you are getting while using runserver is because of connection error in postgres

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with modwsgi. The error is about your database server.

Comment: I have list of tables in database and I have connected database in settings.py but still not working. What could be the reason? Please help me.@Sanip@Daniel Roseman

Comment: I wrote correct password of user postgres in settings.py. I did "ALTER USER postgres with password 'postgres';" .but also I got password authentication failure for user postgres. Please help me.@Sanip

Comment: Why do you have a space in your username in settings file?

Comment: When I did manage.py runserver,it shows Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ . But when I run the django application in browser ,it displays the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. How can I run the application in browser? @Sanip

Comment: Make sure you have followed the proper instructions for setting your project in apache. You can go through some materials in the internet and follow the instructions as stated.

Comment: Yes , I followed the instructions for setting my project in apache but it doesnot work.@Sanip

Comment: Problem Solved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890449/unable-to-set-a-cron-job-to-take-backup-od-the-postgresql-database @Sanip

Comment: Please help me @Sanip