# Unable to set a cron job to take backup of the postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I have tried to backup postgresql database by using many methods but unable to do.Please help me.

*/etc/crontab*

```
0 6 * * * sudo pg_dump -U USERNAME -h REMOTE_HOST -p REMOTE_PORT NAME_OF_DB > LOCATION_AND_NAME_OF_BACKUP_FILE
```

.pgpass

```
localhost:5432:db_name:postgres:password
```

*/etc/crontab*

```
 0 6 * * *  /home/backup.php
```

backup.php

```
 <?php
    exec('pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase > dbbackup.sql',$output);
    print_r($output);
?>
```

I tried this as well. 
https://dzone.com/articles/linux-database-backup-scheduler-script-postgresql

Comment: Why are you trying to inline the script or put it into php code? Why not bash script with execution bit set?

Comment: I tried but couldn't backup postgresql database.

Comment: It create empty sql file.@ jaroslawj

Comment: instead of using php to backup, you can use shell script. This will make sure that the system backs up the database periodically. This article can be helpful to you https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/postgresql-database-backups-using-cron-jobs.